# How to implement a lazy setdefault?

Tags: python, lazy-evaluation

One minor annoyance with `dict.setdefault` is that it always evaluates its second argument (when given, of course), even when the first argument is already a key in the dictionary.

For example:

```
import random
def noisy_default():
    ret = random.randint(0, 10000000)
    print 'noisy_default: returning %d' % ret
    return ret

d = dict()
print d.setdefault(1, noisy_default())
print d.setdefault(1, noisy_default())
```

This produces ouptut like the following:

```
noisy_default: returning 4063267
4063267
noisy_default: returning 628989
4063267
```

As the last line confirms, the second execution of `noisy_default` is unnecessary, since by this point the key `1` is already present in `d` (with value `4063267`).

Is it possible to implement a subclass of `dict` whose `setdefault` method evaluates its second argument lazily?

---

EDIT:

Below is an implementation inspired by BrenBarn's comment and Pavel Anossov's answer.  While at it, I went ahead and implemented a lazy version of get as well, since the underlying idea is essentially the same.

```
class LazyDict(dict):
    def get(self, key, thunk=None):
        return (self[key] if key in self else
                thunk() if callable(thunk) else
                thunk)


    def setdefault(self, key, thunk=None):
        return (self[key] if key in self else
                dict.setdefault(self, key,
                                thunk() if callable(thunk) else
                                thunk))
```

Now, the snippet

```
d = LazyDict()
print d.setdefault(1, noisy_default)
print d.setdefault(1, noisy_default)
```

produces output like this:

```
noisy_default: returning 5025427
5025427
5025427
```

Notice that the second argument to `d.setdefault` above is now a callable, not a function call.

When the second argument to `LazyDict.get` or `LazyDict.setdefault` is not a callable, they behave the same way as the corresponding `dict` methods.

If one wants to pass a callable as the default value itself (i.e., *not* meant to be called), or if the callable to be called requires arguments, prepend `lambda:` to the appropriate argument.  E.g.:

```
d1.setdefault('div', lambda: div_callback)

d2.setdefault('foo', lambda: bar('frobozz'))
```

Those who don't like the idea of overriding `get` and `setdefault`, and/or the resulting need to test for callability, etc., can use this version instead:

```
class LazyButHonestDict(dict):
    def lazyget(self, key, thunk=lambda: None):
        return self[key] if key in self else thunk()


    def lazysetdefault(self, key, thunk=lambda: None):
        return (self[key] if key in self else
                self.setdefault(key, thunk()))
```

Comment: You can't make it not evaluate the second argument.  What you'd have to do is wrap that argument in a function (e.g., with `lambda`) and then have `setdefault` call the function only if needed.

Comment: Can I suggest you add `*args, **kwargs` to the signatures of `lazyget`, `lazysetdefault`, and the call to `thunk()`?  This would allow your lazy stuff to take parameters.  e.g. `lbd.lazysetdefault('total', sum, [1, 2, 3, 4], start=2)`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, evaluation of arguments happens before the call. You can implement a `setdefault`-like function that takes a callable as its second argument and calls it only if it is needed.

Answer (score 26):

This can be accomplished with `defaultdict`, too. It is instantiated with a callable which is then called when a nonexisting element is accessed.

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(noisy_default)
d[1] # noise
d[1] # no noise
```

The caveat with `defaultdict` is that the callable gets no arguments, so you can not derive the default value from the key as you could with `dict.setdefault`. This can be mitigated by overriding `__missing__` in a subclass:

```
from collections import defaultdict

class defaultdict2(defaultdict):
    def __missing__(self, key):
        value = self.default_factory(key)
        self[key] = value
        return value

def noisy_default_with_key(key):
    print key
    return key + 1

d = defaultdict2(noisy_default_with_key)
d[1] # prints 1, sets 2, returns 2
d[1] # does not print anything, does not set anything, returns 2
```

For more information, see the [collections](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html) module.

Answer (score 16):

You can do that in a one-liner using a ternary operator:

```
value = cache[key] if key in cache else cache.setdefault(key, func(key))
```

If you are sure that the `cache` will never store falsy values, you can simplify it a little bit:

```
value = cache.get(key) or cache.setdefault(key, func(key))
```

Comment: If you're checking `key in dict` there's no point in using `setdeault`

Comment: This will require to search `key` in `cache` twice. Which is not a big deal for dict based on Hash-Map, but still doesn't make so mach sense.

Comment: @user1685095 If you don't call setdefault the cache won't be updated. setdefault is both setting the empty cache and returning its value at the same time

Comment: Not looking up the key twice would be a micro-optimisation from O( "2" n) to O(n). Python's probably the wrong choice if this is an issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25777714/which-algorithm-is-faster-on-or-o2n

Comment: @cz "Not looking up the key twice would be a micro-optimisation from O( "2" n) to O(n)", dicts are supposed to be `O(1)` for most purposes (assuming no collisions).

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be no one-liner that doesn't require an extra class or extra lookups. For the record, here is a easy (even not concise) way of achieving that without either of them.

```
try:
    value = dct[key]
except KeyError:
    value = noisy_default()
    dct[key] = value
return value
```

Comment: Avoids double lookup, and is completely understandable. Could even be a line shorter using;
`value = dct[key] = noisy_default()`

Answer (score 0):

For Python 3.8+ the best I can come with is a function.

```py
from typing import MutableMapping, Callable, TypeVar

K = TypeVar('K')
V = TypeVar('V')
MISSING = object()


def setdefault_lazy(d: MutableMapping[K ,V], key: K, func: Callable[[], V]) -> V:
    if (value := d.get(key, MISSING)) is MISSING:
        d[key] = value = func()
    return value
```

Use case:

```py
d = dict()
print(setdefault_lazy(d, 1, noisy_default))
print(setdefault_lazy(d, 1, noisy_default))
```

You can make your own `dict` class which uses this function like so:

```py
class MyDict(dict):
    setdefault_lazy = setdefault_lazy

d = MyDict(name="John")
print(d.setdefault_lazy('age', noisy_default))
print(d.setdefault_lazy('age', noisy_default))
```