# Swift function taking generic array

Tags: arrays, swift, generics, infinite-loop

I'm trying to write a simple hand-rolled function to flatten a nested array. My code works fine as a switch statement, but not when I'm recursively calling it within a "for i in 0..arr.count" loop. I look at each element in the passed in array and say "if this is an array, call the function and pass this in, else append to the output array".

```
func flatten (input: [Any]) -> [Any] {


    var outputArray = [Any] ()

    for i in 0..<input.count {
        let data = input[i];
        (data is Array) ? outputArray += flatten(input: [data]) : outputArray.append(data)

    }

    return outputArray

}
```

Because my function argument must be of type [Any], I'm forced to pass the "data" variable back into it as [data]. This just forces the function to constantly unpack the array and it just gets stuck in the loop. Any suggestions on how I can avoid this?

Comment: Possible helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40669193/explain-swift-iterators and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40689128/why-are-swift-iterators-slower-than-array-building.

Comment: Also possibly helpful: [Extending Collection with a recursive property/method that depends on the element type](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41640321/2976878)

Comment: Have you tried flatmap?

Comment: @AlexS yes but as stated in the question, I'm opting to hand roll a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start, you're using the ternary operator (`?:`) in quite a complex situation. If you first modify your code to use an `if` statement instead, the compiler error that was appearing in the call to `outputArray.append(data)` - `Generic parameter 'Element' could not be inferred` - appears in a much more sensible place (namely, the line of the if statement).

[image: Generic parameter inference fails]

That error is relatively easy to solve - simply replace `Array` with `Array<Any>`, giving us this:

```
func flatten(input: [Any]) -> [Any] {
    var outputArray = [Any]()

    for i in 0..<input.count {
        let data = input[i]
        if data is Array<Any> {
            outputArray += flatten(input: [data])
        } else {
            outputArray.append(data)
        }
    }

    return outputArray
}
```

At this point, the original problem still occurs, because the value that's passed in to `flatten(input:)` is `[data]`. We know, due to the fact that the `if` condition was `true`, that `data` is really of type `Array<Any>`, and so the value `[data]` must be an `Array<Array<Any>>`. Instead, we want to pass in `data`, which is already an array.

You say that the reason you wrote `[data]` is because the argument has to be an array, and so you were "forced to" by the compiler. In fact, the only thing the compiler is forcing you to do is pass in an argument whose type is declared as `Array<Any>`. We've made sure that `data` is an array using the `if` statement, but `data` is still *declared* as an `Any` (because it was an element of `input`, which is an `Array<Any>`), so the compiler has no idea that it's really an array.

The solution is - instead of using `if data is Array<Any>` to determine momentarily whether `data` is an array but immediately throw that information away - to convert `data` to an `Array<Any>`.

The new `if` statement becomes `if let dataArray = data as? Array<Any>`. The statement `data as? Array<Any>` attempts to convert `data` to an array, returning a value of type `Array<Any>` if successful or `nil` otherwise. Then the `if let dataArray = ...` statement stores the value in `dataArray` and returns `true` if given a non-`nil` value, or returns `false` if given a `nil` value (this is called conditional binding).

By doing that, in the `true` case of the `if` statement we have access to a value `dataArray` that is of type `Array<Any>` - unlike `data`, which is only declared as `Any`. Then `dataArray` can be passed in to `flatten(input:)`, and won't be nested inside another `Array`.

```
func flatten(input: [Any]) -> [Any] {
    var outputArray = [Any]()

    for i in 0..<input.count {
        let data = input[i]
        if let dataArray = data as? Array<Any> {
            outputArray += flatten(input: dataArray)
        } else {
            outputArray.append(data)
        }
    }

    return outputArray
}
```

---

A couple of other notes:

`Array<Any>` is of course equivalent to `[Any]`, so the `if` statement could be written with that (generally preferred) syntax, like so:

```
if let dataArray = data as? [Any] {
    outputArray += flatten(input: dataArray)
}
```

Also, there's no need to go through the whole `for i in 0..<input.count { let data = input[i] ...` ordeal if you just iterate over the array instead, like so:

```
func flatten(input: [Any]) -> [Any] {
    var outputArray = [Any]()

    for data in input {
        if let dataArray = data as? [Any] {
            outputArray += flatten(input: dataArray)
        } else {
            outputArray.append(data)
        }
    }

    return outputArray
}
```