# Flatten [Any] Array Swift

Tags: arrays, swift

Using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24465281/flatten-a-array-of-arrays-in-swift) Stack Overflow question I have the following code.

```
let numbers = [1,[2,3]] as [Any]
var flattened = numbers.flatMap { $0 }
print(flattened) // [1, [2, 3]]
```

Instead of flattened being set to `[1, [2, 3]]` I want it to be `[1, 2, 3]`.

What is the easiest/cleanest way to achieve this in Swift?

Comment: `flatMap` works with an array of arrays, not an array of `Any`.

Comment: @rmaddy Yeah I figured that out, that makes sense to me now. Is there anyway to achieve what I want? Is there some alternative to `flatMap` that will help me achieve what I want?

Comment: Possibly solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42587629/swift-function-taking-generic-array/42599849#42599849

Comment: Is it so unreasonable to think that flatMap should work like this? If you want to flatten a tree you start with an array that has nodes and subarrays for each node.  I don't think this should require an extension. In any case, thanks for the solutions, all!

Answer (score 7):

```
extension Collection where Element == Any {
    var joined: [Any] { flatMap { ($0 as? [Any])?.joined ?? [$0] } }
    func flatMapped<T>(_ type: T.Type? = nil) -> [T] { joined.compactMap { $0 as? T } }
}
```

---

```
let objects: [Any] = [1,[2,3],"a",["b",["c","d"]]]
let joined = objects.joined()   // [1, 2, 3, "a", "b", "c", "d"]

let integers = objects.flatMapped(Int.self)  // [1, 2, 3]
// setting the type explicitly
let integers2: [Int] = objects.flatMapped()        // [1, 2, 3]
// or casting
let strings = objects.flatMapped() as [String]     // ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
```

Comment: Would I be able to do the same thing for Strings?

Comment: In the event that I am mixing types (not happening now, but curious for future reference) how would that work?

Comment: Note that `lazy` is redundant in both cases as you're using the overloads that return arrays (i.e eagerly evaluating). You could rephrase `($0 is T ? [$0 as! T] : [])` as `($0 as? T).map { [$0] } ?? []`, though personally I would probably use a `switch` (e.g https://gist.github.com/hamishknight/eca9b0be62056284ec37c3d49dd7db65). Also, personally I would make `flattened` a method, as it's not O(1); though I know you like your computed properties :)

Answer (score 7):

There may be a better way to solve this but one solution is to write your own extension to Array:

```
extension Array {
    func anyFlatten() -> [Any] {
        var res = [Any]()
        for val in self {
            if let arr = val as? [Any] {
                res.append(contentsOf: arr.anyFlatten())
            } else {
                res.append(val)
            }
        }

        return res
    }
}

let numbers = [1,[2, [4, 5] ,3], "Hi"] as [Any]
print(numbers.anyFlatten())
```

Output:

> [1, 2, 4, 5, 3, "Hi"]

This solution will handle any nesting of arrays.

Comment: You can implement this with a flatMap expression: `self.flatMap{ ($0 as? [Any]).map{ $0.anyFlatten() } ?? [$0] }`

Comment: @Alexander That does work, thanks. But it is really inefficient it seems compared to my less "slick" implementation.

Comment: Where's the inefficiency? Beyond the overhead of closures (which will be completely optimized away in this case)

Comment: @Alexander In a playground testing with the `numbers` array in my answer, the playground shows my `return` statement being called 3 times. When I use your one-line implementation of your `anyFlatten` method, the playground shows the `return` being called 13 times for the same input. Based on that, it seems inefficient. But I haven't done any rigorous tests.

Comment: If I understand your testing method correctly, I think it's quite wrong. Your code's `return` occurs at the end of every recursive call. The number of time your `return` statement is called is equal to the sum of depths of all subarrays. In my code, `return` has the effect of the `.append(contentsOf:)` and `append(_:)` calls in your code. Flattening `Array(0..<10)` (10 elements, all depth 1) would call `return` 10 times for me (10 elements), and once for you (max depth is 1), but that count measures completely different things

Answer (score 5):

Here's an alternate implementation of @rmaddy's `anyFlatten`:

It can be most concisely written like so, but it's quite cryptic:

```
extension Array {
    func anyFlatten() -> [Any] {
        return self.flatMap{ ($0 as? [Any]).map{ $0.anyFlatten() } ?? [$0] }
    }
}
```

Here's a more reasonable implementation:

```
extension Array {
    func anyFlatten() -> [Any] {
        return self.flatMap{ element -> [Any] in
            if let elementAsArray = element as? [Any] { return elementAsArray.anyFlatten() }
            else { return [element] }
        }
    }
}
```