# drop(where: {}) remove(where: {}) function in Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, collections

Is there a function in the Swift Standard library that acts on a collection, takes a predicate and returns the value removed from that collection?

Currently, I have to implement it in 2 steps:

```
guard let idx = allAnnotations.index(where: {$0 is MKUserLocation}) else {return}
let userLocation = allAnnotations.remove(at: idx) as! MKUserLocation
```

But I guess, a similar function exists.

**The goal**

I have the following array:

```
[Type1, Type1, Type1, Type1, Type1, Type1, Type2]
```

`Type2` may or may not be present in the array. There are no other types except these two.

I need to split it onto two elements:

```
[Type1, Type1, Type1, Type1, Type1, Type1]
```

and

```
Type2?
```

That's the function I'm looking for.

Comment: sounds like you are looking for [`filter()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/2905694-filter)

Comment: What is expected if more than one element, matches with the predicate? Currently you are removing the first one.

Comment: @vikingosegundo true, filter is close. I've updated the question to clarify it a bit more.

Comment: What if there are multiple elements of Type2, and also some elements of Type3?

Comment: @PuneetSharma Yes, it's fine. There may be only one element of `Type2`. In particular, I'm splitting `[MKAnnotation]`  into an array of my custom annotations and `MKUserLocation` annotation.

Comment: @MartinR there are no other types except these two.

Comment: @RichardTopchiy https://stackoverflow.com/a/47544741/2303865

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Swift 5 has `removeAll(where)`

```
@inlinable public mutating func removeAll(where shouldBeRemoved: (Element) throws -> Bool) rethrows
```

You can use it like this -

```
var array = [1,2,3]
array.removeAll(where: { $0 == 2})
print(array) // [1,3]
```

[Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/3017530-removeall?changes=latest_minor)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'll mark it as accepted since Swift 5 is the mainstream now. My question was written prior to Swift 5.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an extension that returns an array of dropped elements:

```
extension Array {
    mutating func dropWhere(_ isIncluded: (Element) throws -> Bool) -> [Element] {
        do {
            let reverseArray = try filter { try isIncluded($0) }
            self = try filter { try !isIncluded($0) }

            return reverseArray
        } catch {
            return []
        }
    }
}
```

Just call it like you would call `filter`.

```
var array = [1, 2, 3]
let array2 = array.dropWhere { $0 > 2 }
print(array) //[1, 2]
print(array2) //[3]
```

Answer (score 1):

**Code I've finished with:**

```
extension Array {
  mutating func popFirstElementWith(_ predicate:(Element)->(Bool)) -> Element? {
    for (idx, element) in enumerated() {
      if predicate(element) {
        remove(at: idx)
        return element
      }
    }
    return nil
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `Split` on condition  will slice your array

```
    var typeList =  [Type1, Type1, Type1, Type1, Type1, Type1, Type2]

    var slicedArray:[ArraySlice] = typeList.split { (value) -> Bool in
                return value == YourCondition
            }
print(slicedArray)
```

Comment: `Split` wouldn't work if the element of `Type2` is not at the beginning/end of the array.

Answer (score 0):

This extension takes a predicate and returns the element if it matches the predicate. Also, removes the element from the array.

```
extension Array {
    mutating func popFirstElementWith(_ predicate:(Element)->(Bool)) -> Element? {
        var firstElement:Element?
        self = self.compactMap({ (element:Element) -> Element? in
            guard predicate(element) == true else {
                return element
            }
            if firstElement == nil {
                firstElement = element
            }
            return nil
        })
        return firstElement
    }
}
```

**TEST:**

```
var array:[Any] = ["a", "b", 1, "c"]
let element = array.popFirstElementWith { (element) -> (Bool) in
    return element is Int
}
print(element!)
print(array)
```

**Output**:

```
1
["a", "b", "c"]
```

Comment: Thank you. While the Swift standard library doesn't have such a function, I've accepted your answer. That's exactly what's needed.

Comment: I've modified your code a bit, please take a look at my answer below.

Comment: @RichardTopchiy: In your code you are deleting the first element you found that matches the predicate and return. I guess, it is fine if that is what you desired.

Comment: True, it works exactly the same way as your example. It's fine for my task, as I have only one object to remove.