# Generic Parameter T could not be inferred with optional generic array

Tags: arrays, swift, generics

I have a method in my Model class that has signature below:

`func parse<T: Codable>(data: Data) throws -> Array<T>?`

When I call the method in another class, `Facade`, I get the

> Generic Parameter T could not be inferred

Calling function as below

```
if let data = data {
                do{
                    let parsedArray = try self.model.parse(data: data);
                }
                catch{
                    print(error)
                }
```

gives me the compiler warning on the line where I call the `parse` function.

Comment: you need to explicitly declare the type of the variable you are setting or add another parameter to the  parse method and pass the desired type

Comment: `let parsedArray: [YourType] = try model.parse(data: data)` or  `let parsedArray = try model.parse(data: data) as [YourType]`

Comment: @LeoDabus please put as an answer and I will accept. To be explicit, the type would be the concrete type not T.

Comment: note that your parse method should throw or return an optional not both

Comment: @LeoDabus thanks for the tip. I will accept the answer below, but how would I get back a type that is generic? For instance, in the above example, get back a generic to type later? Is there a way to do this in Swift?

Comment: I think you might be interest in this question also https://stackoverflow.com/a/47544741/2303865

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to explicitly declare the type of the variable you are setting or add another parameter to the parse method and pass the desired type:

```
let parsedArray: [YourType] = try model.parse(data: data)
```