# Swift 4 - FlatMap does not flatten array

Tags: arrays, swift, swift4, flatmap

I'm playing around with Swift and I'm having some trouble with `flatMap`. I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24465281/flatten-a-array-of-arrays-in-swift) StackOverflow question, which describes how to flatten an array of arrays using `flatMap`, but when I reproduce the same code in a playground, it does not flatten the array. I'd appreciate it if someone could provide some insight into what's going on here.

Here's a screenshot of both the code and the result:[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47544741/2303865

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`flatMap` is for an array of arrays; it promotes the inner arrays' contents to be contents of the outer array. And that is *all* it does. It does not magically recurse. It works on an array of type `[[Element]]`, where Element is some single type.

In other words, the flat map of `[[1],[2]]` is `[1,2]`, because that is an array of arrays; its type is `[[Int]]`.

But `[1,[2]]` is *not* an array of arrays. It isn't really an array of *anything*; it makes no sense in the Swift world, where an array's elements must of all be of the same type. So it is merely an array of Any (as your code acknowledges); Swift doesn't even *see* any arrays inside your array `t1`. So `flatMap` doesn't apply.

In an ideal world, your code wouldn't even compile, because `flatMap` used on an array of Any is illegal. Unfortunately there is (or used to be) *another* `flatMap`, and the compiler, having given up on the `flatMap` that applies to `[[Element]]`, resorts to the *other* `flatMap`. It applies to any array, so your code ends up legal (but it *still* does nothing). See [Flatten [Any] Array Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47544675/flatten-any-array-swift).

Comment: Thanks for that explanation, it makes a lot of sense!