# What is this function parameter for?

Tags: swift, generics, types

```
func load<T: Decodable>(_ filename: String, as type: T.Type = T.self) -> T {
    let data: Data

    guard let file = Bundle.main.url(forResource: filename, withExtension: nil)
        else {
            fatalError("Couldn't find \(filename) in main bundle.")
    }

    do {
        data = try Data(contentsOf: file)
    } catch {
        fatalError("Couldn't load \(filename) from main bundle:\n\(error)")
    }

    do {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        return try decoder.decode(T.self, from: data)
    } catch {
        fatalError("Couldn't parse \(filename) as \(T.self):\n\(error)")
    }
}

load("jsonFilePath")
```

The function extracts the data form a JSON.
What is that 'parameter' `type: T.Type = T.self` for? If I remove this parameter the code still works. So what do I need it for?

Comment: Not related to your question but you can use a single do catch

Comment: Regarding your question, You don’t need as long as you explicitly specify the resulting type somewhere

Comment: where do I explicitly specify the resulting type?

Comment: You need to assign the resulting object  to a variable. Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47544675/flatten-any-array-swift/47544741?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C43.7365#47544741

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This parameter is just a helper to use three kind of declarations as below,

```
1) let model: Model = self.load("Countries")
2) let model = self.load("Countries", as: Model.self)
3) let model = self.load("Countries") as Model
```

You can remove it from the method signature if you want to use the first kind of declaration.

Comment: 3) let model = self.load("Countries") as Model

Comment: I am trying to understand where T.self comes in. Is that somehow automatically assumed based on the type declaration in an assignment?

Comment: @Chris Yes, Swift auto inference will figure out the actual type.