# Getting Generic Type UIView from function Swift

Tags: swift

I am trying to make a function that, by given a UIView, it iterates recursively to all the subviews until it finds a UIView of type T. So far I have:

```
func getType(from view: UIView) -> AdaptiveContainerView? {

    for aView in view.subviews {
        if let adapView = aView as? AdaptiveContainerView {
            return adapView
        }
        else {
            return getType(from: aView)
        }
    }

    return nil

}
```

Now I am trying to refractor the function so it gets the UIView type and returns it if found. By UIView type I mean:

```
class MyView: UIView {}
```

My first approach is

```
func getGenericType<T, Q:UIView>(from view: UIView, ofType: T) -> Q? {

    for aView in view.subviews {
        if aView is ofType {

        }
        ...
    }

    return nil

}
```

However I am having the following error:

```
Use of undeclared type 'ofType'
```

Any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47544675/flatten-any-array-swift/47544741

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For **Static**

```
func getGenericType<Q:MyView>(from view: UIView) -> Q? {

    for aView in view.subviews {

        if let res = aView as? Q {

            return res
        }
        else {

            return getGenericType(from: aView)
        }

    }

    return nil
}
```

Call

```
let res = getGenericType(from: self.view) // res of type MyView
```

---

If you need to **dynamically** send the parameter

```
func getGenericType<T:UIView>(from view: UIView,type:T.Type) -> T? {

    for aView in view.subviews {

        if let res = aView as? T {

            return res
        }
        else {

            return getGenericType(from: aView,type:T.self)
        }

    }

    return nil
}
```

Call

```
let res = getGenericType(from: self.view,type:MyView.self)  // res of type MyView
```

Comment: Great!! that was what I was looking for. I was close but you question works as a charm!