# Swift: loop through a collection of type Any?

Tags: swift

I'm new to learning swift and I ran into this issue and can't seem to find an answer for it. I create a collection of type Any that includes a Double, String, Int and Bool. When I attempt to loop through it I get an error:

> "Value of protocol type 'Any' cannot conform to 'Sequence'.

Here is the exercise:

> "Create a collection of type [Any], including a few doubles, integers, strings, and booleans within the collection. Print the contents of the collection."

```
var items: Any = [5.2, "Hello", 2, true]
print(items)
```

> "Loop through the collection. For each integer, print "The integer has a value of ", followed by the integer value. Repeat the steps for doubles, strings and booleans."

```
for item in items {
    if let unwrappedItem = item as? Int {
        print("The integer has a value of \(item)")
    } else if let unwrappedItem = item as? Double {
        print("The integer has a value of \(item)")
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Just cast the object from `Any` to `[Any]`

Comment: The first instruction says "Create a collection of type [Any]." That's not what you did.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were supposed to create an object of type `[Any]` instead of `Any`. Then you can switch each item and cast it to its respective type:

```
let items: [Any] = [5.2, "Hello", 2, true, 2.7, "World", 10, false]

for item in items {
    switch item {
    case let item as Int: print("The integer has a value of \(item)")
    case let item as Double: print("The double has a value of \(item)")
    case let item as String: print("The string has a value of \(item)")
    case let item as Bool: print("The boolean has a value of \(item)")
    default: break
    }
}
```

---

This will print

> The double has a value of 5.2
> The string has a value of Hello
> The integer has a value of 2
> The boolean has a value of true
> The double has a value of 2.7
> The string has a value of World
> The integer has a value of 10
> The boolean has a value of false

---

If you need to iterate each type separately you can use for case let and cast each element to the desired type:

```
for case let item as Int in items {
    print("The integer has a value of \(item)")
}

for case let item as Double in items {
     print("The double has a value of \(item)")
}

for case let item as String in items {
    print("The string has a value of \(item)")
}

for case let item as Bool in items {
    print("The boolean has a value of \(item)")
}
```

---

This will print

> The integer has a value of 2
> The integer has a value of 10
> The double has a value of 5.2
> The double has a value of 2.7
> The string has a value of Hello
> The string has a value of World
> The boolean has a value of true
> The boolean has a value of false

You may also be interest in this post [Flatten [Any] Array Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47544675/flatten-any-array-swift/47544741#47544741)