# Find all the words in a string which have the greatest length

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I want to find all the words from the string which have the greatest length.

At the moment, the result is just the first with the greatest length: `'jumped1'`, whereas I want them all: `['jumped1', 'jumped2']`.

How can I adapt the following?

```
function test(str) {

  var newStr = str.split(' ');
  var nu = 0;
  var word =null;

  for(var i=0; i < newStr.length; i++){
     if(newStr[i].length > nu){
       nu = newStr[i].length; // length
       word = newStr[i]; // word

     }    
  }
  return word;
}

console.log(test("The quick brown fox jumped1 over the lazy dog - jumped2"));
```

Comment: what do you mean by "multiple words"? Do you mean words with numbers on the end or do you want an array of all the words with the greatest lengths?

Comment: @Joe I think they just mean more than 1 word if therss multiple words of the same length

Comment: nop, jumped1 and jumped2, currently it only shows jumped1 , because both are same length (7)

Comment: So if the longest word in the array is length 7, return all words of length 7 ?

Comment: yes . that's it

Comment: @david See my answer, that is what I have described.

Comment: I think putting '>=' instead of '>' in your if statement will return the desired result? and this one => word = newStr[i]; will be word += newStr[i];

Comment: i tried it once, but  :(

Answer (score 3):

Instead of assigning to a variable, `word`, when you find longest word, push it to an array of longest words. You have to handle blanking the array though when a new longest word is found.

```js
function test(str) {
  var split_string = str.split(' ');
  var longest_length = 0;
  var words = [];
  for(let string of split_string){
     if(string.length > longest_length){
       words = [string];
       longest_length = string.length;
     } else if (string.length == longest_length){
       words.push(string);
     }
  }
  return words;
}

console.log(test("The quick brown fox jumped1 over the lazy dog - jumped2"));
```

Comment: 100% genius !, no comments

Comment: @ShanuTThankachan If the answer resolved your issue, please [mark it as accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/289255)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to get the length of the longest word and then [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Filter) to get the list of words of that length:

```js
function test(str) {
  var words = str.split(' ');
  var maxLen = words.reduce(function(num, word){
    return Math.max(num, word.length);
  }, 0);
  
  return words.filter(function(word){
    return word.length == maxLen
  });
}

console.log(test("The quick brown fox jumped1 over the lazy dog - jumped2"));
```

Comment: This is `O(2n)`,  however `O(n)` is possible.

Comment: @JoeIddon Although I see your point, you wouldn't take into account the 2, see [Which algorithm is faster O(N) or O(2N)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25777714/which-algorithm-is-faster-on-or-o2n)

Comment: @NickA Yes, both their execution times scale linearly with the input size, just mine is always twice as fast :). Yours is still a cool functional approach so +1 from me!

Comment: @JoeIddon In theory ;) To the best of my knowledge `reduce` and `filter` perform faster than iteration (although I could be wrong on that!), and likewise to yours for the O(n).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you can use `filter` after finding the max length in order to return an Array of every word with `length === max`

```js
function test (str) {
  let words = str.split(' ')
  let max = 0
  words.forEach(word => {
    if (word.length > max) max = word.length
  })
  return words.filter(word => word.length === max)
}

console.log(
test("The quick brown fox jumped1 over the lazy dog - jumped2")
)
```

Comment: This is `O(2n)`, however `O(n)` is possible.

Comment: Thanks @JoeIddon, I didn't realize how to accumulate in one pass - your answer is elegant

Answer (score 0):

You could reduce the array by collecting longer words or with same length.

```js
function test(string) {
    return string
        .split(' ')
        .reduce((r, w) => {
            if (!r || r[0].length < w.length) {
                return [w];
            }
            if (r[0].length === w.length) {
                r.push(w);
            }
            return r;
        }, undefined);
}

console.log(test("The quick brown fox jumped1 over the lazy dog - jumped2"));
```