# What is the time complexity of this type of program?

Tags: c

i wanted to know what is the complexity of doing two loops when they both do the same amount of loops, like this:

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{

}

for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{

}
```

is it O(n+n) = O(n)?

Comment: would be O(2n) but it's actually O(n) since in time complexity you ignore the constants.

Comment: Yes, $O(n) + O(n) = O(n)$. Check out e.g. Hildebrand's "Short course on asymptotics" (available on his webpage) for the gory details (more geared to analysis, but very relevant).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which algorithm is faster O(N) or O(2N)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25777714/which-algorithm-is-faster-on-or-o2n)