# Understanding the time and space complexity of this problem

Tags: c++, time-complexity, space-complexity

I have the following code. I have been told that the time complexity of this is O(n).
But I am having a hard time understanding how. To me it seems like it is
O(n) + O(n) + O(n) = O(3n)
and the space complexity is O(3n) as well because 3 vectors that get populated to the size of n.
Is my understanding correct ?

```
void productofself(std::vector<int> v)
{
    int multipliedProduct = 0;
    std::vector<int> left;
    std::vector<int> right(v.size());
    std::vector<int> result;
    for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
    {
        if (i == 0) 
        { 
            multipliedProduct = 1; 
        }
        else 
        {
            multipliedProduct *= v[i - 1];
        }
        left.push_back(multipliedProduct);
    }
   
    for (int i = v.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if (i == v.size() - 1) 
        {
            multipliedProduct = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            multipliedProduct *= v[i + 1];
        }

        right[i]=multipliedProduct;
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
    {
        result.push_back(left[i] * right[i]);
    }

}
```

Comment: Constant get removed from big-O since they don't actually matter.  We use it to describe how the algorithm scales, not its actual performance.

Comment: related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25777714/which-algorithm-is-faster-on-or-o2n

Comment: O(n) and O(3n) are the same thing.   Both mean (in your case) that time and space each increase linearly with n  (in the asymptotic case i.e.  as n gets large).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are missing the point of the asymptotic notation. That code *is* O(3n) but it is also O(n) and the latter is what matters.

`O(3n)` and `O(n)` are equivalent by definition.

We say `f(x)` is `O( g(x) )` if there exist two constants `m` and `k` such that `f(x) < m * g(x)` for all `x` greater than `k`. Basically `f(x)` is `O(g(x))` if for sufficiently large `x`, `f(x)` is always smaller than a constant factor times `g(x)`.

So you can see the constant factor right in that definition: `m`. A scaling factor like 3 comes out in the wash. There exists an `m` such that `3 * n < m * n`, namely any number greater than 3. So the function `f(n) = 3*n` is `O(n)`.

Comment: Thanks for clearing this up. Is the space complexity of my problem O(3n) => O(n) as well ?

Comment: @JamesFranco Yes, big-O functions the same with space as it does with time.