# Auto Sum Input Values and Display Using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Basically I want to update an Input field with the sum of all above Input Fields.

This is a part of HTML within  tag:

```
<tr>
                <td width="20%">Admission Fee:</td>
                <td width="80%"><input onchange="findTotal()" type="text" class="input_box" name="admission_fee" id="fee" size="5" value="" maxlength="6" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/, \'\');"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="20%">Annual Fee:</td>
                <td width="80%"><input onchange="findTotal()" type="text" class="input_box" name="annual_fee" id="fee" size="5" value="" maxlength="6" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/, \'\');"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="20%">Paper Money Fee:</td>
                <td width="80%"><input onchange="findTotal()" type="text" class="input_box" name="paper_money_fee" id="fee" size="5" value="" maxlength="6" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/, \'\');"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="20%">Monthly Fee:</td>
                <td width="80%"><input onchange="findTotal()" type="text" class="input_box" name="monthly_fee" id="fee" size="5" value="" maxlength="6" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/, \'\');"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="20%">Remaining Balance:</td>
                <td width="80%"><input onchange="findTotal()" type="text" class="input_box" name="remaining_balance" id="fee" size="5" value="" maxlength="6" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/, \'\');"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="school_trow2" width="20%">Total Fee:</td>
                <td class="school_trow2" style="padding: 3px 0;" width="80%"><input type="text" class="input_box" style="background: #8CDFFF; border: 1px solid #006991; color: #000;" name="total_fee" id="total_fee" size="5" value="" disabled></td>
            </tr>
```

And this is the Javascript I am Using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function findTotal()
        {
            var arr = document.getElementById(\'fee\');
            var tot=0;
            for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
            {
                if(parseInt(arr[i].value))
                {
                    tot += parseInt(arr[i].value);
                }
            }
            document.getElementById(\'total_fee\').value = tot;
        }
        </script>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I've come up with.

- You are using same Id for multiple elements. I added the same class to the elements instead
- You are using `<input type='text'` then checking for numbers using regex. A better approach would be to just use `<input type='number'`
- Since `maxlength` does not work on `type='number'`, I have used `max` to handle 6 digit limit.

```js
function findTotal() {
  const fees = document.querySelectorAll(".fee");
  const total = document.querySelector("#total_fee");
  let sum = 0;
  
  fees.forEach(fee => {
     if(fee.valueAsNumber){
     sum += fee.valueAsNumber;
     }      
  });
  total.value = sum;    
}
```

```html
<tr>
   <td width="20%">Admission Fee:</td>
   <td width="80%"><input onchange="findTotal()" type="number" class="input_box fee" name="admission_fee" value="" min='0' max='999999'></td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td width="20%">Annual Fee:</td>
   <td width="80%"><input onchange="findTotal()" type="number" class="input_box fee" name="annual_fee" value="" min='0' max='999999'></td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td width="20%">Paper Money Fee:</td>
   <td width="80%"><input onchange="findTotal()" type="number" class="input_box fee" name="paper_money_fee" value="" min='0' max='999999'></td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td width="20%">Monthly Fee:</td>
   <td width="80%"><input onchange="findTotal()" type="number" class="input_box fee" name="monthly_fee" value="" min='0' max='999999'></td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td width="20%">Remaining Balance:</td>
   <td width="80%"><input onchange="findTotal()" type="number" class="input_box fee" name="remaining_balance" value="" min='0' max='999999'></td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td class="school_trow2" width="20%">Total Fee:</td>
   <td class="school_trow2" style="padding: 3px 0;" width="80%"><input type="text" class="input_box" style="background: #8CDFFF; border: 1px solid #006991; color: #000;" name="total_fee" id="total_fee" size="5" value="" disabled></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Never use the same `id` for more than one element. This defeats the whole purpose. :)
2. Change the `class` name on the total input field to something other than `input_box`. That way you can select all other `<input>`s by using `document.querySelectorAll('.input_box')`. Than traverse them as you did with `arr` and sum the values, etc.

```js
        function findTotal()
        {
            var arr = document.querySelectorAll('.input_box');
            var tot=0;
            for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
            {
                if(parseInt(arr[i].value))
                {
                    tot += parseInt(arr[i].value);
                }
            }
            document.getElementById(\'total_fee\').value = tot;
        }
```

[Documentation on `document.querySelectorAll()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselectorall.asp)

Comment: One issue with this code that the sum is updating irregularly. I mean if I add 2+2+2 then it shows 6 but if I remove any thing from above then the sum add 2 again. I don't know why but there is some issue in your code.

Comment: Not sure, I only replaced the `document.querySelectorAll('.input_box')` part. If the input field of the total does not have the `input_box` class name, it should select only those other inputs. But maybe there are others on the page with the same class name?

Answer (score 2):

Do what Philip and Ahsan Khan said about the HTML and using classes instead of ids for that.

Then use `map` to parse each value into a integer (or use `parseFloat` if you want float). Finally, use `reduce` to sum everything.

```js
const findTotal = () => {
    const fees = [...document.querySelectorAll('.fee')].map(x => parseInt(x.value));
    const total = fees.reduce((a, b) => a + b);
    document.getElementById('total_fee').value = total;
}
```

[Documentation on `map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Map)

[Documentation on `reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Comment: just out of curiosity, wouldn't adding `map` and `reduce` increase the complexity to `O(2N)` compared to writing the logic in `forEach` to make it `O(N)`? or is the difference isn't significant? (P.S I am still pretty novice in JS)

Comment: First you could `parseInt` in the `reduce`'s lambda if you want, but secondly, it really doesn't matter both O(2n) and O(n) are linear (more about that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25777714/which-algorithm-is-faster-on-or-o2n)

Comment: This was helpful, Thank you Aloisdg!