# Should I consider whether an input value is even or odd when calculating time complexity?

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, big-o

I have the following function:

```
def pascal_triangle(i:int,j:int):
    j = min(j, i-j + 1)
    if i == 1 or j == 1:
        return 1
    elif j > i or j == 0 or i < 1 or j < 1:
        return 0 
    else:
         return pascal_triangle(i-1,j-1) + pascal_triangle(i-1,j)
```

The input value for `j` has the following constraint:

```
1<=j<=i/2
```

My computation for the time complexity is as follows:

```
f(i,j) = f(i-1,j-1) + f(i-1,j) = f(i-n,j-n) + ... + f(i-n,j)
```

So, to find the max `n`, we have:

```
i-n>=1
j-n>=1
i-n>=j
```

and, since we know that:

```
j>=1
j<=i/2
```

The max `n` is `i/2-1`, so the time complexity is `O(2^(i/2-1))`, and the space complexity is the maximum depth of recursion(n) times needed space for each time(O(1)), `O(2^*(i/2-1))`.

I hope my calculation is correct. Now my concern is that if `i` is odd, This number is not divisible by 2, but the terms of function must be an integer. Therefore, I want to know should I write the time complexity like this:

> The time complexity and space complexity of the function are both:
>
> ```
> O(2^(i/2-1)) if i is even
> O(2^(i/2-0.5)) if i is odd
> ```

Answer (score 2):

At a first glance, the time and space analysis looks (roughly) correct. I haven't made a super close inspection, however, since it doesn't appear to be the focus of the question.

Regarding the time complexity for even / odd inputs, the answer is that **the time complexity is `O(sqrt(2)^i)`, regardless of whether `i` is even or odd**.

In the even case, we have `O(2^(i / 2 - 1)) ==> O(1/2 * sqrt(2)^i) ==> O(sqrt(2)^i)`.

In the odd case, we have `O(2^(i / 2 - 0.5)) ==> O(sqrt(2) / 2 * sqrt(2)^i) ==> O(sqrt(2)^i)`.

What you've written is *technically* correct, but significantly more verbose than necessary. (At the very least, it's poor style, and if this question was on a homework assignment or an exam, I personally think one could justify a penalty on this basis.)

Comment: It's not technically correct. It contains constant terms and factors. It's wrong. They should be removed.

Comment: @user207421 What's wrong? You can't mean unnecessary terms/factors which don't make a difference.

Comment: @KellyBundy Yes I can. That is exactly what I do mean. Big-O notation doesn't have them. Any Big-O expression containing them is therefore incorrect.

Comment: No, [there is nothing in the formal definition of Big-O that prevents constants from appearing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25777739/17769815). It's poor style, but it doesn't affect correctness.

Comment: @BrokenBenchmark You cannot cite a Stack Overflow answer as a normative reference or 'formal definition'.

Comment: @user207421 Sure, how about definitions from [NIST's Dictionary of Algorithms and Data Structures](https://xlinux.nist.gov/dads/HTML/bigOnotation.html), [MIT's 6.042](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-042j-mathematics-for-computer-science-spring-2015/readings/MIT6_042JS15_Session24.pdf), or [Rice University's COMP310](https://www.clear.rice.edu/comp310/course/design/big_o.html)? None of these definitions prohibit constant terms from being used in big-O notation.

Comment: @user207421 The fact that O(2n+1) = O(n) is due to the functions n and 2n+1 belonging to the same class of functions. It does not mean that O(2n+ 1) is somehow wrong.