# Cant find what's wrong in the code... Repeat and missing Number

Tags: python, arrays

**Question**

You are given a read only array of `n` integers from `1 to n`.

Each integer appears exactly once except `A` which appears **twice** and `B` which is **missing**.

**Return `A` and `B`**.

**Note:** Your algorithm should have a linear runtime complexity. Could you implement it without using extra memory?

**Note** that in your output A should precede B.

Example:

```
Input:[3 1 2 5 3] 

Output:[3, 4] 

A = 3, B = 4
```

**My code:**

```
class Solution:
    def repeatedNumber(self, A):
        n=len(A)
        asum=0
        rsum = (n*(n+1))//2
        x=0
        dict={}
        for i in A:
            asum+=A[i]
            
            if A[i] in dict:
                x=A[i]
            else:
                dict[i]=1

        
        diff=rsum-asum
        
        return x,x+diff
```

Comment: why you put the function inside a class? for this specific request you can just use a function with def

Comment: because i am solving it on a platform on which i needed to just solve the function

Comment: Programming is not math, you can't omit the `*` when multiplying `(n(n+1))//2`, it needs to be `(n*(n+1))//2`. This would be even more obvious if you had posted the traceback as part of the [MCVE] like you're supposed to.

Comment: but its still not running, giving wrong ans

Comment: Aha, this is a variant on the Lonely Number problem - the standard version of this is that a stream of N numbers will feature around N/2 numbers where there are two of one number, and there will be one instance of a single ("lonely") number.

Comment: You can try keeping tabs on what numbers turn up, but I wonder if there is a bitwise solution, which will have O(N).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be a solution. It runs in *O(2n)*

```
my_list = [3, 1, 2, 5, 3]
new_list = []

length = len(my_list)

for x in range(1,length+1):
  new_list.append(x)

for x in range(1,length+1):
  try:
    my_list.remove(x)
  except:
    missing_number = x
    
double_number = my_list[0]

print(missing_number)
print(double_number)
```

Basically, according to your input, you can use the fact that the max value inside the list is the max length. So you create a new list with all the possible values, scan your first list and removing the values from the second list. If you try to remove a value that doesn't exist in the list you got error (that's why the `try`, `except`) and at the end you get, in the original list, only the double value (as it has been removed just one time)

EDIT: actually, if you consider the execution time of `.remove()` function, the overall running time of the function is *O(n+n^2)*

Comment: I wonder if this might be too helpful, to the degree that the OP can now cheat on something. It's generally best to help them learn instead if you can.

Comment: it is O(n*n), did you not consider list.remove time complexity ?

Comment: @sahasrara62 I'm not considering it, should I?

Comment: yes you should consider it

Comment: @sahasrara62 ok, I thought the assignment wouldn't taake into consideration inbuilt python function

Comment: Be careful, you shouldn't write O(2n) but O(n). Edit: in your edit, time complexity is O(n^2) not O(n + n^2)

Comment: i think its using more space as u initialised a new list

Comment: @Pauuuuuuul why? there are two for loops, each of them run n time

Comment: yup time complexity is all right

Comment: That's not how the Big O notation works. If you had k for loops of time complexity O(n) (where k is a constant), the overall complexity of your program would still be O(n).

Comment: @Pauuuuuuul _O(k*n)_ is more accurate as you get more info. At least this is what have taught me at Uni

Comment: Assuming k is a constant (as I specified in my previous comment), you don't add any info writing O(k*n), time complexity is still linear with respect to the size of the input so you should write O(n). Look at this as I it is better explained than what I could come up with in the comment section: [Which algorithm is faster O(N) or O(2N)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25777714/which-algorithm-is-faster-on-or-o2n)

Answer (score 1):

Your error is simple, you're using `for i in A:` but you refer to i within the for loop as if you did `for i in range(len(A)):`. To fix this all you need to do is replace all instances of A[i] in your code with i. It should look something like this:

```
class Solution:
    def repeatedNumber(self, A):
        n=len(A)
        asum=0
        rsum = (n*(n+1))//2
        x=0
        distinct={}
        for i in A:
            asum+=i
            
            if i in distinct:
                x=i
            else:
                distinct[i]=1

        
        diff=rsum-asum
        
        return x,x+diff
```

Note: It doesn't have any functional relevance in this case, but it is generally go practice to name your variables something other than the object name. In this case I just renamed the dict variable to distinct, as it also gives readers a better understanding of what the dictionary is actually used for.

Comment: dont use inbuild function name for object name

Comment: Alright I'll edit that in, thanks!