# Generate factors of a number in ascending order in O(1) memory

Tags: python, memory, runtime, big-o, generator

I was asked to create a function that is given a positive integer `num`, and returns a generator, that when iterated over, it will return all of `num`'s divisors in ascending order.

Implementation requirements:

- Runtime of O(sqrt(n))
- Memory complexity of O(1)

I was able to meet the runtime requirement but couldn't figure out to solve the problem in O(1) memory (ie. without using a list, tuple, string etc.)

Here's my code so far.

```
def factors(num):
    higher_divisors = [0] * int(num ** .5)
    index = 0
    for i in range(1, int(num ** .5) + 1):
        if num % i == 0:
            yield i
            if i != num // i: # don't include the square root twice
                higher_divisors[index] = num // i
                index += 1

    for i in range(index - 1, -1, -1): # yield the higher divisors in reverse order
        yield higher_divisors[i]

def main():
    num = 100
    for i in factors(num):
        print(i)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 2):

The trick is to run the loop twice, once forward, once backwards.  This will achieve both the time and space complexity requirements.

```
def factors(num):
    mid = int(num ** .5)
    for i in range(1, mid + 1):
        if num % i == 0:
            yield i
    for i in range(mid, 0, -1):
        if num % i == 0 and (num // i) != mid:
            yield num // i
```

How the space complexity is satisfied is apparent (i.e. all memory usage is well defined as constant regardless of input).

How the time complexity is satisfied requires a bit of understanding on what Big-O actually means: it ultimately means the shape of the curve which time (or space) requirements grows with regards to the input, i.e. the specific growth rate.  [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25777714/which-algorithm-is-faster-on-or-o2n) has answers that dives into what that means, so best to reference that, and also the wikipedia article on the [properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Properties), which states that "if an algorithm runs in the order of n<sup>2</sup>, replacing n by c<sup>n</sup> means the algorithm runs in the order of c<sup>2</sup>n<sup>2</sup>, and the big-O notation ignores the constant c<sup>2</sup>."  Hence, the algorithm above may look like O(2*sqrt(n)), but given that constants are ignored, it really is O(sqrt(n)).

Comment: Yeah, that's a lot cleaner. I got stuck in the mindset that I got both factors in a pair when looping through only once.